# Removing li when no href with jquery from div

Tags: jquery

I have a div as below:

```
<div id="DivInteractive">
        <p><strong>INTERACTIVE ONLINE BROCHURE</strong></p>
        <ul>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank"/></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.espireinfo.com" target="_blank">Internship brochure Interactive 2008</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">OPUS EU Flyer Interactive 2009</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.rai.com" target="_blank">2009 PLI Interactive Brochure</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://cmsstag/index.aspx" target="_blank">Worldwide brochure Interactive English 2009</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to remove the **li** if there is no **href** coming from above div through jquery
in above case when page will be loaded, it will remove the first li and my output will be as given below:

```
<div id="DivInteractive">
            <p><strong>INTERACTIVE ONLINE BROCHURE</strong></p>
            <ul>

                            <li><a href="http://www.espireinfo.com" target="_blank">Internship brochure Interactive 2008</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">OPUS EU Flyer Interactive 2009</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.rai.com" target="_blank">2009 PLI Interactive Brochure</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://cmsstag/index.aspx" target="_blank">Worldwide brochure Interactive English 2009</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
```

Please suggest any solution using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$("#DivInteractive li:has(a[href=''])").remove();
```

Comment: I want to remove only for the div id="DivInteractive" not for all

Comment: Its not working as in my page it is coming down to page. I think i need to check in complete page.

Comment: This code is working on my local machine and in the Google AJAX APIs Playground. Which version of jQuery are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so great with regex, but to add to Cletus' answer, I would do:

```
$("#DivInteractive li:has(a[href='regex(check for on or more spaces)'])").remove();
```

This way, it would remove it if the href was set to "" or " " or whatever.